# HTML contact form send email by php but after send not stay that page

Tags: php, html

I was using these code in index.php for send email

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {
$admin_email = "md.alhussain365@gmail.com";
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$subject = "Website Visitor";
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
mail($admin_email, "$subject", $message, "From:" . $email);
echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
else  {
?>
form id="contact-form-face" class="clearfix" method="post">
<input type="email" name="email" value="Email" onFocus="if (this.value ==       'Email') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Email';" />
<textarea name="message" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Message') this.value = '';" onBlur="if (this.value == '') this.value = 'Message';">Message</textarea>
<input class="contact_btn" type="submit" value="Send message" />
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

And everything works as I want. Like after sending a message stay page in same section (contact us).

[image: after send message I want]

But now my client doesn't want use index.php she wants to use index.html

That's why I separate the php code into other file. It works fine but it's going new page and showing one line text that I fixed. But I need to stay page like before.

So please tell me, How can I do same as did I before?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please don't post code as images, in particular images as links.  You need your code to be searchable and copy/pasteable.  You can [edit] your question to remove the images and replace them with actual code (select the code block and press ctrl-K to format it properly).

Comment: Please don't use images for your code. [Edit] the question and include the code.

Comment: U can use ajax request to send mail. and after success set ***thankyu message* using jquary..

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup **index.php** as DirectiryIndex in WebServer configuration
2. Use URL without file names
3. ???
4. PROFIT

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions.

Comment: Removed it, sorry :)